# PHP Unicode in JSON

Tags: php, json, unicode

I'm sending a JSON POST body to my PHP web service that looks something like this:

```
{
    "foo": "☺"
}
```

When I echo out the body in the PHP, I see this:

```
{
    "foo":"\xe2\x98\xba"
}
```

I've also tried sending the `\uXXXX` equivalent:

```
{
    "foo": "\u263a"
}
```

This got further, in that the raw JSON string received had `"foo":"\\u263a"`, but after `json_decode` the value turned to `\xe2\x98\xba`.

This is causing problems when I come to use the value in a JSON response. I get:

```
json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument
```

At its simplest, this is what happens why I try to JSON encode the string:

```
> php -r 'echo json_encode("\x98\xba\xe2");'
PHP Warning:  json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument in Command line code on line 1
```

**My question is**: how can I best get this smiley face from one end of my application to the other?

I'd appreciate any help you could offer.

Comment: How did you "[...] echo out the body [...]"?

Comment: `echo "\xe2\x98\xba";` works; shows the correct unicode smilie.

Comment: @PleaseStand I sent it to error_log with `error_log(file_get_contents('php://input'))`.

Comment: @rossmcf Could you post the lines that are throwing the error, please?

Comment: You need to understand the relationship between Unicode characters and their UTF-8 encodings. All that you are showing is correct, but context matters.

Comment: @Mifeet I've added them to the question.

Comment: @rossmcf ok, see my udated answer. Does it help?

Comment: @Mifeet Aha! As PleaseStand said, the byte order is out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the correct behavior of json_encode. If you use the following:

```
<script>
    alert(
     <?php
       $a = "☺";
       echo json_encode($a);
     ?>
    );
</script>
```

The HTML output will be `alert("\u263a");` and the alert will show `☺` since `"\u263a"` is a correct representation of the string in JavaScript.

Usage of [`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) constant as the second parameter of `json_encode` in PHP is also an option, but available only for PHP 5.4.0 or newer.

In what scenario do you intend to use the value?

---

**Edit:**

> php -r 'echo json_encode("\x98\xba\xe2");'
>
> PHP Warning:  json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument in Command line code on line 1

The problem is you use a wrong sequence of characters. It should be

```
echo json_encode("\xe2\x98\xba"); // this works for me
```

instead of

```
echo json_encode("\x98\xba\xe2");
```

Comment: I think you're on to something here. The value needs to be returned as JSON, and that's where I'm having trouble.

Comment: @rossmcf So you want to send a string with that character as JSON reponse from PHP, right? And what is the trouble? If the JSON response is processed by JavaScript, it should behave correctly even if the result is `\u263a` instead of `☺`.

Comment: The trouble is that json_encode won't encode `'\x98\xba\xe2'`, at least in my version of PHP.

Comment: @rossmcf I think the problem is somewhere in the code you're not showing us. My guess is there is an inappropriate double conversion.

Comment: I've just added some more detail to the question. It seems to be a problem with json_encode when dealing with the internal representation of the string, i.e. '\x98\xba\xe2'.

Answer (score 3):

PHP's `json_decode()` function behaves correctly given your input case, returning the sequence of [UTF-8](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) bytes (`E2 98 BA`) that represent the character.

However, Apache HTTPD applies the `\x` escaping (in function [`ap_escape_logitem()`](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/server/util.c?revision=1485409&view=markup#l1802)) before writing the line to the error log (as you did for testing purposes using [`error_log()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)). As noted in file [`server/gen_test_char.c`](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/server/gen_test_char.c?revision=1330189&view=markup#l123), "all [...] 8-bit chars with the high bit set" are escaped.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you encode you have to use 
`json_encode({
foo": "☺"}, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`

Basically json_encode function works only for UTF-8 encoding so before you encode check the encoding of string,like this .

```
 mb_check_encoding("your string", 'UTF-8') ;
```

if it returns false then you can convert to utf-8 using

```
utf8_encode("your string");
```

Comment: Thanks Arun. When I tried your suggestion, json_encode outputted: "\u0098\u00ba\u00e2", which is three other characters altogether.