# Decode unicode control characters in JSON string

Tags: php, json, unicode, character-encoding, control-characters

### Situation

I'm importing huge JSON files into a database. It contains fields that were filled in by users using an online wysiwyg editor. This allowed them to also paste in special characters, typically copied from a MS Word document.

### Problem

After decoding the JSON file, a couple of special characters are left out. Turns out most of them are [unicode control characters](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cc/list.htm) for example † which is character [U+0086](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0086/index.htm).

### Example

```
<?php
$json = '{"test": "start \u0086 end"}';
$decoded = json_decode($json);
echo $decoded->test . PHP_EOL;
```

**Output:**

```
start  end
```

**Expected output:**

```
start † end
```

### Temporary fix

For the moment I applied this dirty fix, but I'm still looking for a more elegant way to replace **all** unicode characters.

```
protected static function replaceUnicodeCharacters(&$string)
{
    $replace = [
        "\u0086" => "†",
        "\u00b0" => "°",
        "\u0093" => "“",
        "\u0094" => "”",
        "\u0091" => "‘",
        "\u0092" => "’",
        "\u009c" => "œ",
        "\u00f6" => "ö",
        "\u00f9" => "ù",
        "\u00ad" => "­",
        "\u0096" => "–",
        "\u00fb" => "û",
        "\u00a0" => " ",
        "\u0085" => "…",
        "\u00ab" => "«",
        "\u00bb" => "»",
        "\u008c" => "Œ",
        "\u00c0" => "À",
        "\u00ff" => "ÿ",
        "\u00fc" => "ü",
    ];

    $string = str_ireplace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $string);
}
```

Comment: Not one of my test browsers manages to display the “UTF-8” version of this character on https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0086/browsertest.htm correctly, only the decimal/hex HTML escape seem to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

0x86 when interpreted as Windows-1252 is †. You're just missing an encoding step:

```
$decoded->test = mb_convert_encoding($decoded->test, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8");
echo '<html><meta charset="Windows-1252">';
echo $decoded->test . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: For me this results in `start � end`. Echoing the charset is not possible as I'm using a console application.

Comment: Then set the console's encoding appropriately. Looks like you have configured it to display UTF-8, but as I'm trying to get across here is that your data is in Windows-1252.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** [PHP Unicode in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895908/php-unicode-in-json)

I hope maybe at least, that helps...

Comment: This yields NULL on PHP 7.3 and Uncaught JsonException: Syntax error in php shell code:1 with **`JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR`** enabled

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry. Just tried to help. :(
This is because this character is not supported by most of the browsers, maybe. PHP can't display the cross properly D: I guess.